# How can I recognize a mouth and teeth within a face on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-image

I know that Core Image on iOS 5.0 [supports facial detection](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/) ([another example of this](http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/01/ios-facial-recognition/)), which gives the overall location of a face, as well as the location of eyes and a mouth within that face.

However, I'd like to refine this location to detect the position of a mouth and teeth within it. My goal is to place a mouth guard over a user's mouth and teeth.

Is there a way to accomplish this on iOS?

Comment: Editing questions to make them more readable and help the community is one thing, but completely re-writing them and adding sentences that didn't exist is another. @Brad Larson adding 'i know that core image on iOS 5 supports facial detection'. The user may know this, but how can you presume this. The only reason I point this out, is because I mentioned this fact in my answer and it makes my answer look like I didn't read the question at all!

Comment: @bandejapaisa - The asker linked to a tutorial about Core Image on iOS 5.0 (stated right in the title of the linked blog post), so I wanted to express what was at that link in case it went dead at some point in the future. They then indicated that this was insufficient for their needs, so I clarified the question to indicate why Core Image was not a good solution. I feel that this was a justified addition, given the contents of the links they present.

Answer (score 9):

I pointed in [my blog](http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.jp/2012/03/coreimage-and-uikit-coordinates.html) that tutorial has something wrong.

Part **5) Adjust For The Coordinate System**: Says you need to change window's and images's coordinates but that is what you shouldn't do. You shouldn't change your views/windows (in UIKit coordinates) to match CoreImage coordinates as in the tutorial, you should do the other way around.

This is the part of code relevant to do that:
(You can get whole sample code from [my blog post](http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.jp/2012/03/coreimage-and-uikit-coordinates.html) or directly from [here](https://github.com/nacho4d/FaceDetectionExample2). It contains this and other examples using CIFilters too :D )

```
// Create the image and detector
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageView.image.CGImage];
CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace 
                                          context:...
                                          options:...];

// CoreImage coordinate system origin is at the bottom left corner and UIKit's
// is at the top left corner. So we need to translate features positions before
// drawing them to screen. In order to do so we make an affine transform
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform,
                                       0, -imageView.bounds.size.height);

// Get features from the image
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:image];
for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features) {

    // Get the face rect: Convert CoreImage to UIKit coordinates
    const CGRect faceRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(
                              faceFeature.bounds, transform);

    // create a UIView using the bounds of the face
    UIView *faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceRect];

    ...

    if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition) {
        // Get the mouth position translated to imageView UIKit coordinates
        const CGPoint mouthPos = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(
                                   faceFeature.mouthPosition, transform);
        ...
    }
}
```

Once you get the mouth position (`mouthPos`) you simply place your thing on or near it.

This certain distance could be calculated experimentally and must be relative to the triangle formed by the eyes and the mouth. I would use a lot of faces to calculate this distance if possible (Twitter avatars?)

Hope it helps :)